# How to define input types in Matlab Coder for a function that has a varying number of input?

Tags: c, matlab, compilation, mex, matlab-coder

I have a function let's say `sq_dist()`. This function can be called like this `sq_dist(a,b)` or `sq_dist(a)`. This function includes slow operations and thus I am trying to make a Mex version of it hoping that it will run faster. I am using the Matlab Coder GUI to do so.  In order to define input types (in the define input screen) i use a function that calls `sq_dist(a,b)` and sq_dist(`a`) to automatically determine input. This gives me an error:  `Error determining type for input sq_dist:b. Index exceeds matrix dimensions`. Here is my function:

```
n = 50; 
dim = 50; 
a = rand(n, dim);  
b = rand(n, dim); 

u = sq_dist(a, b); 
v = sq_dist(a);
```

So, since sq_dist can be called in different ways I am not sure how to define its input in the Coder.

If i manually set the input to `double :inf x :inf` for `a` and `b` the mex file is compiled but i get a runtime error:  `Function 'sq_dist' called with wrong number of arguments: expected 2, received 1.`

Answer (score 1):

In short, you cannot do what you want to do (with current version 2016a) for the top-level function - this has to have a defined number of inputs and outputs. Even if you use the 'varargin' parameter in the function definition, MATLAB Coder will generate the function with a fixed number of inputs based on the example arguments you provide.

If you have a particular function that has a variable number of input arguments, you can put a wrapper function (with a fixed number of input arguments) around the outside, and make the wrapper the top-level function.

Rules here:
http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/rules-for-using-variable-length-argument-lists-for-code-generation.html